# servicestack: adding www-authenticate header to an error response

Tags: servicestack

When throwing an 401 error because of missing authorization, I want to include the www-authenticate header.

But how do I do that?

I tried with a response filter, but that didn't seem to work.

**Edit**

My response filter ain't called when a httperror is thrown:

```
appHost.ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, obj) => res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "Basic realm=..."));
```

Exception handlers are called but the added header is not part of the response (according to both Chrome dev tools and [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com))

```
appHost.ExceptionHandler += (req, res, name, exception) => res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "Basic realm=...");
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context on what didn't work in your response filter? After adding the AuthFeature plugin and creating a Global Response Filter to add a header record, I POSTed invalid credentials to '/auth/credentials'. I received a 401 and my filter added the header.

Comment: I'm not using the AuthFeature - there could be some difference there. My response filter didn't run at all. I will try once more and see if I can post some code if it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any hooks where I can add to the response headers:

- `ResponseFilters` ain't called after an exception is thrown.
- `ServiceExceptionHandler` doesn't provide the response object.
- `ExceptionHandler` is called *after* the response is sent, so it's to late.

Since I check for credentials in a request filter, I have access to the response object there. I ended up with a custom exception `LogonException` which I can trap and add the header:

```
appHost.RequestFilters.Add(
    (req, res, obj) => 
    {
        var creds = request.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword();

        try
        {
            myService.logon(creds);
        }
        catch(LogonException)
        {
            res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "Basic realm=...");
            trow;
        }
    });
```